# Scrolling single line, long text, in TextView

Tags: java, android, user-interface, scroll, textview

Please have a look at the following simple code.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="John Jonathan Samuwell Abbruzzi"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
```

The text in `TextView` is larger than the width of the screen and should be in single line. I added `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`, so the user can scroll it to see the rest of the text. But, it is not happening. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your textview inside the `HorizontalScrollView` its working i am tested..

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="John Jonathan Samuwell Abbruzzi"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use HorizontalScrollView with single line. If you want horizontal scrollbar for multiple views then you can create layout in HorizontalScrollView and scroll complete. HorizontalScrollView can only hold one direct child.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="my view" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```